# AlarmManager.setExact() does not work

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I wrote an application which is able to set alarms based on some specif times. These specific times change day by day. For example, sunrise time changes every day. So, I defined a main activity which is responsible to call setExact() method every night at 11:55 p.m and then it has to set tomorrow's alarms based on the specific times for tomorrow. The issue is, it does not work! When I set the alarm, it just works for one time, and it is not going to be set for the second time. I really need help. Thank you :)

```
public class MainPage extends AppCompatActivity {

private Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

protected GoogleApiClient client;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setMainAlarm();
  }
  private void setMainAlarm() {
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(".mainAlarmReciever");
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Calendar alertCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    alertCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR,23);
    alertCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,54);
    alertCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,59);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        alarmMgr.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
    }else{
        alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
    }

}
```

This is the related receiver class for that:

```
public class mainAlarmReciever extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AlarmSetter.createOrUpdateAllAlarms(context);
    this.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

Comment: "When I set the alarm, it just works for one time" -- `setExact()` only triggers one event. If you want to repeat, either use a `setRepeating()` variant (which is not exact on API Level 19+), or have your `mainAlarmReceiver` call `setExact()` again for the next alarm.

Comment: Yes, I see! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you do not set the mainAlarm for tomorrow on your `mainAlarmReciever`.

Imagine that your `mainAlarmReciever->onRecieve` run at 11:54:59 P.M tonight. And it does whatever tasks you want to do. You should also set the mainAlarm for Tomorrow at 11:54:59 P.M in your onRecieve function.

Another option is using setRepeating (as CommonsWare mentioned it is not exact after API 19+).